# Survival analysis: How to deal with new information as time progresses?

Tags: survival

Imagine we want to know the survival function for hotel guests getting into the pool, given a few controls:

- Each guest stays exactly 24 hours at the hotel
- Guests always apply sunscreen just before going to the pool, and much prefer getting in the pool when the temperature is warmer
- For every minute (future and historical) we have updated data on the outside temperature and whether or not each guest is applying sunscreen at that moment. Assume that temperature forecasts do not exist in this scenario.

The easy, if not naïve, approach would be to initialize each sample (guest) with the outside temperature when they check into the hotel and a boolean status of if they have sunscreen on or not. However, when we apply that model to new guests we're not using the live minute-level temperature & sunscreen status data after they've checked in. **How can you properly incorporate that data to generate a new survival function every minute for the remaining time of each guests' stay?**

What I've tried so far is to create minute-level samples for each guest that include a 'time since checking in' variable while holding the target variable constant (e.g. each minute-level sample for each guest has the same target of (Uncensored, 238 minutes) or (Censored, 1440 minutes)). Is this a valid approach? With my real data, the naïve approach listed above has a C-index of 0.56 and the minute-level approach has a C-index of 0.75. I'm suspicious that the dramatic performance improvement is due to introducing bias toward the longer, censored data. Do I need to do some type of stratified sampling to re-balance the samples before training?

Comment: Your "failure is "getting in the pool"? If you were doing this with a Cox PH model (you may not be of course) you can simply have a time-varying covariate set as the predictors in your model - the model is known as an Anderson-Gill model for the "intensity" of the process (model has same form as a Cox PH model). This is an example of a "dynamic" model - i.e. time-varying covariates. If multiple failures are permitted (multiple dips) then a lagged variable of number of previous dips could be used. This will give **very** different inference compared to using baseline covariates only.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed: time-varying covariates. I found this lecture which explains them well: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~rxu/math284/slect7.pdf . 
This seems to be implemented by default in R (as explained in the link above) and for Python the lifelines library has an implementation (https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Time%20varying%20survival%20regression.html)

Comment: Glad this helped. The first link alludes to a good point: time varying covariates in a Cox PH model means the model is no longer a PH model - this is no problem if we simply recognize the model as one method of extending the PH model (same functional form for covariates, same baseline hazard function, still estimated semi-parametrically). Thus the fact it is not proportional hazards is fine, as long as you are aware. The main point to note (you may be aware of this) is using time-varying covariates following randomization a designed experiment is a big deal - can lead to introducing bias

Comment: Final point on bias: if prediction is more important then a model with biased estimates that predicts well is still useful to predict (maybe variables in the model are a proxy for the real variable causing the responses). So reservation about time-varying covariates tend to be much more in the realm of designed experiments. Also in a standard Cox PH with only baseline covariates, since the risk set (numbers subjects at risk) varies over time, there is an implicit time-varying dependence built in - indeed it has been shown hazard ratios can be biased even with no time-varying covariates.

Comment: Repeated events with same form as Cox PH are called Anderson-Gill models for the intensity (same as hazard). Since lagged response variable, or function of it (i.e. number of past events) is a great predictor of the future, one can model repeated events within a subject with this approach (perhaps also with other time-varying covariates). Conditional on the (rich) covariate set the residuals are Martingales (nicely behaved stable processes) that allow the model to give good estimates. Omitting all this and using only baseline variables leads to un-explained variability

Comment: Using only baseline covariates (poorer covariate set) can be modelled with "marginal" AG-type models (after model is fitted "naively" assuming martingale residuals, the within subject covariances are empirically estimated). Thus covariate choice (static/baseline only Vs time-varying) leads to different models - both are fine, just different approaches. But again if prediction is primary aim then static covariates need not be adhered to.